# having problems in converting string date to weekday

Tags: java, date, days

I have a date string in the form month/day/year, i want to get only the day of the week for the selected date, and then match the day with my db for further processing. Kindly help

Comment: split with "/" and take 1 element bu array[1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949242/a-very-simple-java-code-to-get-date-of-a-week-day-but-very-strange-result-i-g

Comment: the string is already split into three integers. i need the day of week

Answer (score 1):

Use the class [**GregorianCalendar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), it has method that can help you

Answer (score 0):

if **dateString** contains the date in form month/day/year, you can split it into an array as follows:-

```
String[] splitDate = dateString.split("/");
```

The day would be the 2nd element of the **splitDate** Array

```
String day = splitDate[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
    java.util.GregorianCalendar class.
    there is constructor with date,month,year as parameters.
    Then there is a method to get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou so much. i m doing it like this

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cyear);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,cmonth); //week 37 of year 2010
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,cday);
int i= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```